# How do I call a C++ function that sets the values of an int array from C#?

Tags: c#, c++, .net

I have the following function in C++ inside a .dll:

```
extern "C"
{
   __declspec(dllexport) void ColorRamps_getColorRampTable(int n, int *table);
}
```

It takes in an array with n elements and sets the array values.

**How do I call this from C#?**

I understand that I must first DllImport the function (?):

```
[DllImport("ColorRamps.dll")]
static extern void ColorRamps_getColorRampTable(int n, int[] table);
public static void getColorRampTable(int[] table)
{
    int n = table.Length;
    ColorRamps_getColorRampTable(n, table);
}
```

Is this correct?

When I call getColorRampTable(int[] table) must I pin the array?
How do I do this?

I tried:

```
int[] table = new int[164];
GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc(table, GCHandleType.Pinned); 
getColorRampTable(table);
handle.Free();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options. One is to rely on the .NET marshaller, another is to use unsafe code.

Both are actually quite simple for your case. The marshaller one:

```
[DllImport("ColorRamps.dll")]
static extern void ColorRamps_getColorRampTable(int n, [In, Out] int[] table);

public static void getColorRampTable(int[] table)
{
    int n = table.Length;
    ColorRamps_getColorRampTable(n, table);
}
```

<strike>This has a slight overhead in that the marshaller copies the array to unmanaged memory first, and then copies it back into your array again.</strike> **EDIT:** As Xanatos correctly noted, since `int[]` is a blittable type, the marshaller actually cheats and passes a pointer to your actual array. Or at least that's the documented behaviour.

If this is a performance problem for you (and it's a real, measured problem - don't do this otherwise), you can pass a pointer to the .NET array directly using unsafe code:

```
[DllImport("ColorRamps.dll")]
static extern void ColorRamps_getColorRampTable(int n, int* table);

public unsafe static void getColorRampTable(int[] table)
{
    int n = table.Length;
    fixed (int* pTable = &table)
    {
      ColorRamps_getColorRampTable(n, pTable);
    }
}
```

The class has to be marked with the `unsafe` keyword, and you have to enable unsafe code in the project settings.

**EDIT:**

As above, this doesn't actually apply for the `int[]` case. I'm going to leave it in here because it's true for non-blittable types, but `int[]` *is* blittable, and the marshaller should just pass the pointer directly, while handling the pinning for you. You should still use the `[In, Out]` attribute, though - even though it will usually behave as In/Out by default, the contract should be clearly specified.

> The main difference is that in the first case, the C(++) code never has access to any of the managed memory of yours - it always works on *copies* of the data. By adding the `[In, Out]` attributes, you're telling the marshaller to not only copy the data in, but also to copy it out after the call is done - otherwise your `table` array would never change.
>
> On the other hand, the second variant passes a pointer to the actual array you're using on the C# side - this may or may not be faster, depending on way too many things, and it's generally slightly more unsafe (be very careful about specifying the correct length of the array, for example).

**Another EDIT:**

There's also an option to use `IntPtr table` in the P/Invoke method declaration, which allows you additional flexibility. The easiest example would be just pinning the array, which is equivalent to the `fixed` case:

```
var hTable = GCHandle.Alloc(table, GCHandleType.Pinned);

try
{
  ColorRamps_getColorRampTable(n, hTable.AddrOfPinnedObject());
}
finally
{
  hTable.Free();
}
```

And even allowing you to explicitly manage the copying quite easily:

```
var pTable = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(sizeof(int) * table.Length);

try
{
  Marshal.Copy(table, 0, pTable, table.Length);

  ColorRamps_getColorRampTable(n, pTable);

  Marshal.Copy(pTable, table, 0, table.Length);
}
finally
{
  Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pTable);
}
```

This is a decent workaround if you can't use `unsafe` code for some reason, but do remember that it's just as "unsafe" as `unsafe` code in most scenarios. The truth is, since you're interacting with native code, you're *always* (somewhat) unsafe - a bug in the native code can easily corrupt your whole application.

Comment: *This has a slight overhead in that the marshaller copies the array to unmanaged memory first, and then copies it back into your array again.* Being `int` a blittable type, and being `int[]` a single dimensional array of a blittable type, there is no marshaling, but simply automatic pinning. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75dwhxf7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: For the "unsafe" example, I suggest using `int* pTable = table` that is compatible with zero-length arrays (the `pTable` becomes NULL)

Comment: For completeness: there is a third method... Doing manually the pinning with `GCHandle.Alloc` and passing a `IntPtr`

Comment: @Luaan: thank you very much! I will use the first approach since this is simplest. What happens when one do not specify the marshalling of an argument ([In, Out])? Is there a default marshalling? Maybe [In] in my case?

Comment: @xanatos Yeah, there's a lot of things you can do once you're working with `IntPtr` - allocating the extra memory yourself, for example. I'll update that.

Comment: @Andy `[In]` is the default. But due to the marshaller optimalization noted in the link Xanatos provided, it can actually behave as `[In, Out]` in some scenarios. Rather annoying if you ask me, but... :D

Comment: From MSDN: "As an optimization, arrays of blittable types and classes that contain only blittable members are pinned instead of copied during marshaling. These types can appear to be marshaled as In/Out parameters when the caller and callee are in the same apartment. However, these types are actually marshaled as In parameters, and you must apply the InAttribute and OutAttribute attributes if you want to marshal the argument as an In/Out parameter." I guess that means I can safely drop the GCHandle in the first approach(?)

Comment: @Andy Yeah, definitely - you only need explicit pinning when the reference you're passing is going to be used *after* the method call ends (for example, in some asynchronous API). That's why even with pointers, you usually use the `fixed` clause rather than `GCHandle` - the pinning is usually scope-based. `GCHandle` has many interesting uses, but you don't need it in this case. The marshaller will handle the pinning (or copying) for you.